# How do I ask this question about a SF author?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question

Frank Herbert's way of thinking is almost completely inside his books. Between the very few of his writes outside, there is [an article](https://vasil.ludost.net/dunegenesis.pdf) resuming what his books are about and how he wrote these books.

Only one of the fans of his Science Fiction material could give context to a phrase in that article that I want to understand. Since the only users that can do that precisely are SF&F SE users, how do I do to avoid admins closing [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203291) as off-topic?

Comment: Just to clarify something, none of the close voters are moderators. Close voting (VTC) is a "privilege" awarded once one reaches 3000 reputation; mods can VTC as well, and their vote is binding, but most of the closing is done by the community after having been out in a review queue. **TL;DR**: no mods closed this, a couple users did, who might have had their reasons but unfortunately didn't elaborate in the comments (unless there's deleted stuff that I can't see).

Comment: It’s late for me so I may be remembering wrong but isn’t the quote talking in the general sense about the **real** world rather than something *fictional**?

Comment: Good to know @Jenayah, thanks again for clarify these things!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yes and no, because all his books are truly about those real world issues disguised in fictional world. I don't know if describe it as analogies or metaphors, but anarchy is in the plot everywhere. The article talk much about it.

Comment: @Jenayah The consensus seems to be that explaining VTCs (and downvotes) often leads to arguments and flamewars. I know *I* feel compelled to explain myself, but I understand why many users prefer not to ;)

Answer (score 8):

Kind of an "if it's only about the real world, it's off-topic; if it's about how it's tied to *Dune*, it's murky" situation.

Disclaimer: I'm certainly not the most knowledgeable person about *Dune* in these parts, but I don't think that's a problem.

---

I don't understand why this question was closed, at least not as "off-topic". From what I get by reading the question and (admittedly skimming) article, this is a written piece:

- by the author of a major SF work;
- talking about said work;
- in *Omni* (the magazine).

And the question asks about the meaning of a sentence in the context of that *Dune* explanation. So far, I'm not seeing anything blatantly off-topic.

If I understand that right, this is basically asking "what does *Dune* tell us about Herbert's statement of humans​ not having equal ability", which I think falls under literary analysis. Per [Is literary analysis on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11833), this is on-topic as long as it can be answered without (too much) speculation. Typically these could fall under "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based", but certainly not off-topic.

Once again I only know the very big outlines of *Dune* (shoot me), but for the peasant I am, it seems big enough of an universe and "behind the scenes" info for the question at stake to be answered (in a way that fits SE's format).

---

It might put some people off that it's been [cross-posted on Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/37917), but I'd argue that a SFF answer backed with quotes etc wouldn't be redundant with the answers there - so far there's only one undetailed mention of a character, Vlad Harkonnen.

To put it in a nutshell, I think the question is fine as is and should be reopened (and [voted as such](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/139891)). I may be missing something though, and as I'm unsure whether the uncertainty stems from my lack of *Dune* knowledge, my misunderstanding of one​ of our policies, or something else, I'm looking forward to clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis! I came from the Physics and IT SE when the focus is "help people to understand things" and I feel like in a ["to-may-to to-mah-to" situation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181757/correct-clear-concise-way-to-use-potato-potato-in-writing#answer-181759) since the author thinking is just the book message.

Comment: If it's been cross-posted by OP then it's incredibly simple. It doesn't get re-opened; [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/262849) (Spoiler: No).

Comment: If anything, it ought to be significantly revised to make it different from the repost (and maybe concentrate on the relation to *Dune* more). Then they could maybe coexist.

Comment: @TARS That is I want to know. I'm concerned in Herbert works, not if he has right in his point of view.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk Then start by editing the question more into that direction. You might even be able to *include* information from the [politics.se] discussion in order to refine your SciFi question further (and thus make it both on-topic *and* sufficiently different from the cross-post). (Though, if it's *significantly* different, maybe a reask here would work better altogether. A *bit* of an unfortunate situation you've maneuvered yourself into, I admit.) ;-)

Comment: @TARS that is exactly the help I need, to edit my question to be on-topic to share insights with Science Fiction experts.

Comment: You are right @TARS I was beaten by the system. I commented like crazy there, but most of the theme is a subtle anti-communist talk, they are Politics of course. Too much hours translating back and forth, trying to answer the question in the books myself too, was too much work. And now I'm losing rep for down-votes here, I just quit. Thanks for the help anyway, I appreciate your time answering.

Comment: +1 In that this question is *borderline* on-topic. However, judging by the comments it's already looking dangerously off-topic, since it invites discussion of real-world history and issues, instead of focusing on how it influenced *Dune* :/

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I might have been tempted to vote to reopen as simply being on-topic (for the reasons Jenayah mentioned in her answer) but since you've cross-posted this question on Politics:SE where it appears to be on-topic and well received, **per the standing site-wide policy, you can't cross-post something unless it's already been poorly received and/or failed to receive an adequate response.**

- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/262849) (Spoiler: No, it isn't).

Comment: Ah, right, had forgotten that one. Perks of posting at 5 am. Then the usual applies: OP is welcom to ask on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) anytime (I guess [literature.se]'s chat works too).

Comment: Huh, I knew this question looked familiar. I'd already spotted it on the HNQ list from Politics.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the problem is they concern about equality there, and not about Herbert's way of thinking. I write [an answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12278/how-do-i-ask-this-question-about-a-sf-author/#answer-12282) to develop this.

Comment: Seeing as the MSE policy you link applies to the *asker*, and not to close/reopen voters, I'm going to VTRO anyway.

Comment: @Kevin - There's nothing to stop you doing so. That being said, and in the absence of a significant edit from OP to justify the existence of a cross-site duplicate, I'd expect a passing moderator to simply reverse your vote.

Comment: @Valorum: An on-topic question was asked here on SFF.  The fact that there is another question on an entirely separate site is none of our business, and I'd be *very* annoyed if "a passing moderator" did anything of the sort.  Questions do not belong to the OP, they belong to the site, and we have the right to decide which questions we want to answer on our own.  This case is clearly not an example of an OP trying to "game the system" as your linked question contemplates.

Comment: @Kevin - It's not an *entirely separate site* (like Quora, for example), it's part of the same Stack Exchange family of sites.

Comment: So what?  It's not our site.  There's no policy requiring us to keep a question closed after it has been re-asked on another site.  Your linked answer is about a different situation.

Comment: @Kevin - The agreed policy is that you can't ask the same question on two different sites unless there's a bloody good reason. "Because I didn't like the answers I got elsewhere" is not one of those reasons :-)

Comment: @Valorum: I'm not asking the same question on two different sites, so the policy does not apply to me and my VTRO.

Comment: @Kevin For better or worse, network policy when an OP posts an identical question to multiple sites is to close and delete one or the other (if both are on-topic, then choose which to keep according to which is answered or better received). I might have deleted this one already if not for the OP making the effort to tailor his question to be different on both sites.

Answer (score 2):

My vote is a hesitant "it should be allowed". Let me explain:

I was about to vote to close (again, it seems), because in order for a question to be on-topic here it's not enough for it to be about the thoughts of a scifi author; it must be *about scifi*, and this seemed to me to be about Frank Herbert's thoughts on evolution and equality. Much like Einstein's thoughts on songwriting wouldn't be accepted as valid Physics questions, Herbert's thoughts on evolution shouldn't be accepted in a site about scifi...

...except the quoted thought was specifically discussing the thoughts put into the creation of *Dune*, which is on-topic. So it should be allowed, but being careful that the focus is on how this influenced *Dune*, and not in whether Herbert's thoughts were correct or how they apply to the real world.

The danger of off-topicness is definitely there: already I see people commenting under the question on irrelevant (to scifi) matters, such as whether Herbert's thoughts are accurate or how they apply to policies from the history of the US ("separate but equal", etc).

Answer (score -2):

sorry to reply my question but think is important to know that posting the question in Politics (as I was asked to) is emptying answers of crucial context.

You may notice that the discussion there lacks of understanding of certain Herbert's ideas about humans flaws, power attracting corruption, stangment in societies, and many more relevant topics covered in the books...

I could write **"John Smith" instead of "Frank Herbert"** and the question in [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37917) would has the same answers. That is a proof to me is misplaced there.

The interest there is discussing if Herbert was right or not, which has a lot of sense to a politic exchange, but **that was not my question**.

Comment: Alas, your question is asked there (by you, I might add). If you don't like the answers you're getting, might I suggest you prod people with comments or raise a bounty.

Comment: @Valorum I'm commenting there like crazy. My only insight until now is Herbert could be elected if alive, that is rare because he was kind of an anarchist xD

Comment: I suggest you edit the Politics.SE question to focus more on the political view being expressed (irrespective of who wrote it) and edit the SFF.SE question to focus more on Herbert's views in the wider context of his writing. Then perhaps both questions, suitably targeted to the respective communities of experts, can coexist on the network.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm not sure that what you're suggesting would be acceptable (since the other question already has upvoted answers) and the differences you're suggesting are very minor indeed. Thinking outside the box, perhaps OP could ask to disassociate from the other (Politics) question entirely?

Comment: @Valorum They're not very minor, if one question is about a political statement taken in a vacuum and the other is about the views of a sci-fi author. And the idea that disassociating could make a difference seems rather to go against the principle of "vote for the post, not for the poster".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Call me old-fashioned, but if someone asked me "*What does x mean?*", the very first thing I'd want to know is *"Who said it?"*, regardless of whether they'd intentionally tried to obfuscate the author.

Comment: @Valorum And yet, the top answers on Politics SE are addressing the quote in a vacuum without regard to who wrote it. If that's how Politics SE approaches such questions, let them do that, and meanwhile we can put our Herbert experts to work.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I would appreciate your insights about the last edition made to the question, if you have time to check it. I want to make clear the focus in SF readers opinion.